# Python site packages: How can I maintain for both 2.x and 3.x version

Tags: python

I understand that we can install different version of Python on a same box - but there are packages that are not supported common to both.

So if I have two version of Python(2.x and 3.x) installed how can I automatically have packages deployed correctly for each version of Python using pip?

Comment: The virtualenv package is your friend. It will maintain independent installations and environments.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, virtualenv does seems to be the best solution

Comment: I ended up with 3 (three) Python versions which I needed to be installed in my development environment, one of them I had to compile myself. It's not good to have to rely on the distro's versions under such circumstances. virtualenv saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on Arch Linux, and presumably on other distros, there are two separate packages for pip, which if both installed give you two different commands: pip and pip3. Running `pip ...` will always install to the Python 2 site-packages, and `pip3 ...` to the Python 3 site-packages. This works both for system-wide packages (running as root) or for installing them into your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can configure pip to install packages for multiple Python versions automatically, but it's easy to [manually specify two packages on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions), and it would be trivial to write a script that would call pip multiple times with the correct Python versions.